# Opening saved HTML pages / Browser as a User Interface

Tags: javascript, html, json, browser

My question is two-fold: one concerns the mechanics of opening a saved html file in a browser (no internet connection) and the other concerns utilizing the browser as a user interface for a desktop image viewing program I'd like to write.

Basically, I have several hundred albums (folders) with a variable number of images (50 or so) in each and I would like to be able to load all the images in an album on one scrollable screen and also have a way to open other albums (a comboBox or form or whatever it's called).

The first problem I discovered is that apparently javascript intentionally makes it impossible to search through directories and enumerate the files.  That makes sense since any other way would be an obvious security risk.

I learned that a server-side scripting language like php could do what I need (I know nothing at all about php) however, it seems that php requires that I am running a web server like Apache (again, I don't really know what I'm talking about so forgive me) which I really do not want to do.  I would not feel comfortable running a server as I do not know how to operate it securely. Plus it seems like a lot of overhead.

I have a possible (ugly) solution in mind and I'm currently considering exactly how it might be implemented.  Basically, I thought that I could include a list of the album directories in a index HTML page as hyperlinks (which I would update by hand as needed).  The hyperlinks would link to a template html page for the images and include the album name as a query string.  Javascript code would read the query string and form the URL of that album.

In each of those albums, there would be a JSON file that stores the exact number of images in that album, and the images themselves which will be named in numeric order (img1.jpg, img2.jpg, etc.).  The javascript then reads the json file and starts adding the images whose URL's it was able to essentially guess.

It's actually surprisingly difficult to find information about JSON.  It seems that the only way to access a JSON file is with an XMLhttpRequest.  That made me start to wonder how a web browser (Chrome if it is different for each) handles the distinction between server and client when the page is running on your own pc.  Will an XMLhttpRequest work since I am not running a server?  Or am I technically already a server and a client as well? And if so, can I just use php without running Apache?  Also, how exactly does HTTP fit into this?  Does the browser still send out HTTP requests that just are immediately intercepted by my pc before they go to my router or does it get information by an entirely different mechanism?

The above string of questions is the real purpose of this post but since I've already explained everything, I thought I might as well ask if anyone has any ideas or sees any glaring problems with the process I outlined above.  I'm not new to computer programming but am new to internet programming so there may be obvious things I'm overlooking.

Thanks to all who read this bloated post so far!  I do appreciate it and I hope to hear your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if i understood your question right then what you want to achieve is basically make a Gallery sort of app which lets you go through the pics in your specified album in a browser (offline).

Now, the expression i got from your statement is that those files will be fairly static with static names like album1/image1.jpg, album1/imgage2.jpg, album2/image1.jpg and so on. Now as you are in offline mode and will be reading them directly from your directories. It won't be a problem what so ever! You are thinking in the wrong direction, what you are confused in (reading client's directory) is not the problem here as you will be designing a page which will run offline on client machine and won't be hosted on a server. So that's not a problem. I presume you are fairly new at html, javascrript programming.

Fear not! So here is what you should do, i will give you an overview of stuff you will have to do. First, work a bit on the UI, like how those images will be displayed. Roughly it will be something like this: A div on the top for images to display and a div with shorter height at the bottom with albums list. You will populate the album's list and images in just two simple loop (considering you know number of albums/images). So you will be creating those images in a loop, basically giving 'src' of each image like:

```
for(var i=0; i<your number of albums; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<number of pics in that album; j++){
         <image class="img" src="album"+i+"/image"+j+".jpg">
    }
}
```

That's roughly how you will be populating your images.. Now the browser will simply first load the UI and then populate the image containers with these src you have provided (from user's directory, without an issue). Then the rest will be event listeners from next, previous buttons, new album selection etc.

I hope i understood your problem right and gave good enough explanation. Oh and one more thing, in order for it to run on all machines (but online), you can host these pics online and in src, give the url of each pic like http://dropbox.com/axndk/album1/image1.jpg.. something like that. If you have any other questions or confusion, we can have a detailed discussion on that and i'd love to help you as well. Regards

*EDIT:* Reading an image from your directory and displaying it in browser is not an issue, try this simple html and open it in browser to get an idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <img src="Your image's complete path will come here" style="width:304px;height:228px">   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed reply and you are correct, I am very new to HTML/javascript and am totally self taught.  I understand your idea about the nested for loops but am unclear about how I would know the upper bound for j.  This number will be different for each album

Comment: for that comes a bit of general programming logic.. you can store images count of each album in an array like, array[0] will contain images count of first album, then you can use the loop like: for(var j=0; j<array[i]; j++)/// and there you have your different images count for each album.

Comment: Thanks again just one final question: How do I make that array.  I thought that javascript has no ability to examine directories.

Comment: Didn't you say you'll know the albums and images in them beforehand? So i was talking in that perspective when you know all the albums, pics.. Only then you'll be able to give their absolute paths